# Create only an opening div tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Okay, so I have searched this site quite a bit and I can't seem to find the answer, so I am going to ask the same question with a better reason. I am trying to use jquery to add an opening div tag. When I try to use the after I end up with . I understand that jquery does not like to natively create tags like I want. However, here is the situation:

I have a dynamic form generator that I am using to display a form. There are several  headers I am using as section headers from within the form. I want to use the jquery accordion, and it wants to see a div element wrap the contents of the accordian frame, and it wants to see it directly after my . The problem is that the number of elements in between the opening and closing div tag is dynamic. So I can't just wrap something and be done with it. What I want to do is something like this:

```
<h3>Section 1</h3>
```

...Dynamic code section here

```
<h3>Section 2</h3>
```

I want to use jquery to end up with something like this:

```
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>
```

Dynamic code section here

```
</div>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>
```

More dynamic code

```
</div>
```

I know that I can find elements that I know of (the h3 tags) and insert the html. The problem is that jquery won't let me. Apparently it doesn't trust me enough to balance things out on my own. Anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work??

Comment: when you hit problems like this, usually is because bad design, you should think in a redesign

Comment: I'm open to suggestion. If you are going to say something like that, at least point out where you think the bad design is or provide a solution if you know better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
$('h3').each(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll(document.createElement('div'));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ph8D2/

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it didn't work. Interesting though. I am not a jquery expert. Is that basically saying "start at one h3 set and go to the next h3 set and then wrap the whole thing in a div tag"? If so, it's close but not quite what I need. The h3 tags need to be outside the wrapping div. The accordian looks for the h3 tag and then looks for a sibling container to represent the panel.

Comment: Yeah, it basically selects an `h3`, goes to the next sibling, and then selects from this sibling until the next `h3`, and wraps them all in a div... Let me update my answer though, for multiple h3's.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the demo fiddle to more accurately represent what I am trying to do. When you look at it, notice that the accordian does not work. Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/ph8D2/1/

Comment: Actually, I played around a little bit more and updated the fiddle again and I think I got it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/ph8D2/2/ Now to test this on my actual code....

Comment: ahren - You are awesome and you saved my bacon! I need to tweak the styling a bit, but it works awesomely!!!!!!!!

Comment: @AndrewCasey: Make sure that you understand what is happening here - from your other comments it looks like it would be great if you could rethink what everyone here said when answering your question. This answer works for you, but make sure you understand, why it does not work the way you stated in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it's literally impossible to insert an opening or closing tag, thank god. It's not jquery that's preventing you, it's the DOM api. It doesn't make any sense to insert an opening tag because that's not a valid entity.

Just do something like

```
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div class="dynamic">

</div>
```

and

```
$('.dynamic').html( .. your dynamic content ..)
```

Comment: Completely right. Although there were browsers that were actually able to receive HTML part-by-part and at the end construct the DOM as if these parts were passed all as one string. I am not sure, which one was it: Opera or IE.

Comment: I can't do what you suggested. The entire page is a dynamic form, and I need to integrate the accordian into the form in such a way that the different panels make up different sections of the same form.

Comment: One other thing. It may not make sense to insert an opening tag in that fraction of a second, but the closing tag will also be inserted at a later point. I'm actually trying to create balanced html here. And I thought the whole point of jquery was to be able to manipulate the DOM?? Don't get me wrong, I understand the need to create a balanced DOM, and it's exactly what I want to do. I also understand that I am not trying to do something "out of the box", so to speak. If I was, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @AndrewCasey: At the moment you will inject the HTML into the document, it must be processed by the browser. And because browser needs some object structure and forgives mistakes of web developers, it will treat your code as final and will correct it. At the end, you will have DOM elements (and you cannot have eg. half or 23% of DOM element, so you cannot just finish it later with closing tag). And jQuery is based on JavaScript - learn it first, it is important. And stop thinking on the document as HTML - for your code it is already Document Object Model.

Comment: @AndyRay: I am upvoting your answer, it is worth it.